# Laravel 5.1 manualy clearing views cache, caused error 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I just removed all files inside `laravelApp/storage/framework/views` and all of routes now return error 500.

Command `php artisan views:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` tested, but had no affect.

Error reporting is set to `E_All`, `APP_DEBUG` is true both in `app.php` and `.env` file, But i see only a simple error 500 (generated by browser).

How can i fix it?

Comment: see `storage/logs/<env>.log` for exact error, where `<env>` is current environment, e.g. `storage/logs/dev.log` or `storage/logs/prod.log`

Comment: There is only a `laravel.log` file (70MB). My app name is local and i don't see `local.log`. Renamed `laravel.log` with underline, refreshed a route but no new log file created. @limonte

Comment: my bad, in Symfony2 log file is named by env by default, in Laravel it's `laravel.log`. It that log you will find what exactly happend

Comment: Solved. By changing permission of all folders, problem solved. New view cache files generated and everything is now OK. :)

Comment: it's a hole in security to change permission of all folders. Consider not to do this in future, but change write permissions only to folder where it needed.

Comment: You're right, i'll change it soon. Thanks @limonte

Answer (score 0):

i set permission for my folder that cointain all files
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/myweb
(ubuntu)
and it is ok!